# How can I pass parameter to a template in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Say I have this as template.xhtml:

```
<div class="span4">
    <ui:insert name="column1">
        <h2>#{heading}</h2>
            <p>#{paragraph}</p>
    </ui:insert>
</div>
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="column1">
        <ui:param name="heading" value="My Heading" />
        <ui:param name="paragraph" value="My Paragraph" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

However, it does not work. I see neither a heading nor a paragraph.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parameters are defined in the wrong place :

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="heading" value="My Heading" />
    <ui:param name="paragraph" value="My Paragraph" />

    <ui:define name="column1">

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Everything inside the `<ui:define />` is replaced when rendering.